# Problem querying XML in SQL Server result

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I need some help - I have this XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SELECT  @xml = (SELECT TOP(1) codigo, Numero, fecha, transportista, chofer 
                FROM @tbl
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT ('root'));

SELECT 
    @xml.query('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <soapenv:Body>        <CrearViaje4 xmlns:unis="http://unisolutions.com.ar/">{for $x in /rootreturn $x/*}</CrearViaje4></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>');
```

in the line `<CrearViaje4 xmlns:unis="http://unisolutions.com.ar/">`

I just need `<CrearViaje4 xmlns="http://unisolutions.com.ar/">`

but if i delete ***:unis***

when i exectute my sentece it doesnt show the information

Comment: What is your source XML?

Comment: "xmlns:unis" is defining an XML namespace, so it makes sense that if you remove it your results would change if other sections are referencing it. Like @David Browne stated, what is your source XML?